# Fraction function returning unreduced fraction

Tags: python, python-3.x, fractions

I'm trying to convert a mathematical expression into a reduced fraction. When using the Fraction function from the fractions module I get an unreduced fraction.

The code

```
from fractions import Fraction

print(Fraction(1 + 1/(2 + 1/2)))
```

returns `3152519739159347/2251799813685248` which reduces to `7/5`.

I would like my code to return the reduced fraction.

Comment: 3152519739159347/2251799813685248 does not reduce to 7/5.

Comment: You're building a fraction from an imprecise float - don't do that.

Comment: If you want to do fraction math, you need to use `Fraction` from the start, not after all the math has already been done with floats.

Comment: `3152519739159347 * 5 - 7 * 2251799813685248` -> `-1`.

Comment: @DyZ, out of curiosity - what is this neat calculation saying? Thanks

Comment: Use `Sympy` module?

Comment: @AriK `a/b = x/y` if and only if `ay - bx = 0` (with `b, a not 0`)

Comment: @user2357112 I've tried it in 3 different calculators and I get 1.4 every time.

Comment: asgarth: That's because the calculators are doing floating point, not integer, math.

Comment: @asgarth: Calculators have limited precision. (Also, you really need to learn the principles of arithmetic, not just how to use a calculator. 2251799813685248 doesn't end in 0 or 5, so it's not a multiple of 5, and no fraction with 2251799813685248 as denominator can simplify to a denominator of 5.)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga super cool! Thanks

Comment: @user2357112 But I understand what you're saying about using fractions from the start. Basically, my original expression should utilize the Fraction function instead of, say, 1/2. Thank you!

Comment: @user2357112 Understood. I see that now. Thanks.

Comment: by the way, the fraction `3152519739159347/2251799813685248` is perfectly reduced

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is due to the imprecision of floating point math.

While it is true that `1 + 1/(2 + 1/2)` should reduce to `7/5` (or `1.4`), the decimal `1.4` cannot be precisely represented by floating point numbers

```
>>> '{:030f}'.format(1.4)
1.39999999999999999999911182158029987
```

That inaccuracy is leading it to produce a different fraction than `7/5`

If you want precise fraction math, you need to do the entire equation using fractions and not mix it with floating point numbers.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to work with fractions, you need to perform all the operations in exact math, not just convert to `Fraction` at the end. That means no dividing `int`s by `int`s - that'll give you a float.

```
from fractions import Fraction as F

1 + F(1, 2 + F(1, 2))
# or, taking advantage of how int/Fraction gives a Fraction,
1 + 1/(2 + F(1, 2))
```

Otherwise, you'll lose precision to floating-point rounding, and you'll be stuck with options like using `limit_denominator` to guess what the unrounded result might have been.

Comment: `1 + F(1, 2 + F(1, 2))` is already a `Fraction`, you shouldn't need to send it to `F` again

Comment: You can also do `F(1)/2` or `F('1/2')` to get something a bit more readable than `F(1, 2)`.